# Obtaining a static auth token for Google APIs

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I want to add a row to a Google Spreadsheet using PHP and the following library: https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client which seems to be pretty simple.

However, I don't know how to obtain the required access token via the suggested Google's https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client library. I do not want my users to authenticate using OAuth, it is my server side, I just want to have a static access key somehow. It looks like the API has changed since the developer of the php-google-spreadsheet-client has used it?!

- How to obtain a static access key from Google?
- If not possible, how to obtain one without redirecting the user?

Is it possible to obtain such a key via https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody interested: Google is coming up with a solution to the problem called "service accounts": https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Accounts

Unfortunately it is not supported by many Google APIs yet. In the meantime one can run the "normal" OAuth authentication process once with the service user and cache the cookie for future use.

Alternative solution: use the old Zend framework and rely on Google API v1 instead of v3.